# Inner Join Multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have three table with name called tblStock, tblModel, and tblAltStockPrice.

tblStock:

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
| StockCode | Description |          StockModel        |
|-------------------------|----------------------------|
| 1Y 1111   |    ORING    |    CATERPILLAR 950 LOADER  |
|-------------------------|----------------------------|
| 2K 4501   |    BUSHING  |    CATERPILLAR 950 LOADER  |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

tblModel:

```
|------------------------------------|
| ModelCode |     ModelDescription   |
|------------------------------------|
| C950      | CATERPILLAR 950 LOADER |
|------------------------------------|
```

tblAltStockPrice:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| StockCode |    Price    |    UpdateTime   |   UpdateDate  |
|-------------------------|-----------------|---------------|
| 1Y 1111   |      40     |    12:52:41     |   30/12/2013  |
|-------------------------|-----------------|---------------|
| 1Y 1111   |      45     |    12:11:17     |   30/12/2013  |
|-------------------------|-----------------|---------------|
| 2K 4501   |      40     |    12:13:14     |   30/12/2013  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

Problem:

I wish to retrieve the MAX(UpdateTime) AND MAX(UpdateDate) record of joining up this three table.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tblStock s 
INNER JOIN tblModel m ON s.StockModel = m.ModelDescription 
INNER JOIN tblAltStockPrice asp ON s.StockCode = asp.StockCode 
WHERE m.ModelCode='C950' 
ORDER BY MAX(updateTime) AND MAX(updateDate)
```

The output is:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| StockCode |    Description   |   ModelCode    |    ModelDescription      |   Price |    UpdateTime   |   UpdateDate  |
|------------------------------|----------------|--------------------------|---------|-----------------|---------------|
| 1Y 1111   |       ORING      |      C950      |  CATERPILLAR 950 LOADER  |  40     |    12:52:41     |   30/12/2013  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

My expected output is:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| StockCode |    Description   |   ModelCode    |    ModelDescription      |   Price |    UpdateTime   |   UpdateDate  |
|------------------------------|----------------|--------------------------|---------|-----------------|---------------|
| 1Y 1111   |       ORING      |      C950      |  CATERPILLAR 950 LOADER  |  40     |    12:52:41     |   30/12/2013  |
|-----------|------------------|----------------|--------------------------|---------|-----------------|---------------|
| 2K 4501   |       BUSHING    |      C950      |  CATERPILLAR 950 LOADER  |  40     |    12:13:14     |   30/12/2013  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Can anyone correct my mistake?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause so that `MAX` aggregates by stock code, not aggregating all the rows. Also, multiple ordering criteria should be separated with comma, not `AND`. Finally, in your ordering, the date should have precedence over time.

```
SELECT * FROM tblStock s 
INNER JOIN tblModel m ON s.StockModel = m.ModelDescription 
INNER JOIN tblAltStockPrice asp ON s.StockCode = asp.StockCode 
WHERE m.ModelCode='C950' 
GROUP BY s.StockCode
ORDER BY MAX(updateDate), MAX(updateTime)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94d1b0/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try `LEFT JOIN` on tables `tblStock` and `tblModel`

Comment: That would help if there were unmatched rows. But all his rows have matches.